# How to draw a Rectangle around the Window? (When I know its handle)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, draw

The effect that I want is:

[image]

Yeah.. it is similar effect in spy..
It works perfectly when I am doing this on controls inside the WindowForm
or WindowForm that does not have a borderstyle.

However, when it comes to a WindowForm that has a FormBorder,
it FAILS! The rectangle forms inside the form:

[image]

For drawing the rectangle, I used the source from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9741/Screen-Captures-Window-Captures-and-Window-Icon-Ca).

Comment: There may be some help for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634743/non-client-painting-on-aero-glass-window

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine ACTUAL windows form size (with all nonclient elements) when running Aero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838621/how-to-determine-actual-windows-form-size-with-all-nonclient-elements-when-run)

Comment: I found that it is very difficult to draw on the form border with the window handle
so, I just chose to draw on the desktop!

I simply used GetDestktopWindow() API.

Thanks for everybody's comment!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an earlier comment, you can just draw on the desktop using the GetDesktopWindow() API.