# font size big in linux compared windows

Tags: java, swing

I created a simple application in Java swing. I developed this application in Windows OS.
But when I moved this application to Linux, the Font sizes are giving big compared to Windows.
How do I make a standard font size in all across the platform?

Comment: Font is one of taxatios for crossplatfom, Font is based on resources that came fron native os

Comment: Ok.Thanks. So how to make it standard font size? Because of this font size, texts ares cut off in the buttons. It is not visible properly.

Comment: @user414967 Normally, if you used Swing features properly (especially LayoutManager's, and not force min/pref/max size), you shouldn't have much trouble of Cross-platform looks.

Answer (score 2):

Let your chosen layout adapt to the host platform's default font by invoking `pack()` on the enclosing `Window`. Because `pack()` "causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents," you won't have to worry about the different sizes. There are many good [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html); here's a [counter-example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can install Microsoft fonts on your Linux system. Here is a blog post about that: [How to Install Windows Fonts in Java on Linux](http://www.perfectabstractions.com/blog/how-to-install-windows-fonts-in-java-on-linux).