# Is it okay to use setPreferredSize when using a custom panel?

Tags: java

From previous experience, everyone will say "Don't use those `setXxxSize` methods! Use a layout manager!" However, what should I do in this case?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
    public Game() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hi this is a game");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new GamePanel());
        f.pack(); 
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class GamePanel extends JPanel {
        private GamePanel() {
            setPreferredSize(600, 600);
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            //paint stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This is just some example code I threw together real quick. What should I do when I need to make the game area, say, 600 by 600? Is it okay to use `setPreferredSize` here? I don't know of any layout manager that can just take a single component and give it a size, and even if there is, isn't it a lot easier to just use this instead of having to use an entire layout manager?

By the way, `f.setSize(600, 600)` doesn't work here because it takes into account the frame decorations (title bar, border things).

So the question is if I only have one component that needs to be a specific size, what do I do?

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod yes, I saw that, but it doesn't really answer my question. If I only have one component that needs to be a specific size, what do I do?

Comment: What is the intended superclass of `GamePanel`?

Comment: @trashgod oh oops, `JPanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812478/230513) and not just `setPreferredSize()`?

As `Game` is a `JPanel` that is

- Used solely for drawing,
- Contains a default layout but no components and
- Has a standard UI delegate,

the difference is negligible. There are still reasons to override `getPreferredSize()`

- The intent is clear to other developers; demos and prototypes, like zombies, never go away.
- Any one or all of those conditions may change as the class evolves.
- It's an idiomatic reminder not to fall into [this trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

Answer (score 4):

Override `getPreferredSize`, in `GamePanel`:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(600, 600);
}
```

Comment: doesn't that essentially do the same thing?

Comment: If you want to allow variable sizes, you'll have to keep a `preferred` reference, changing it as required, and returning it instead.

Comment: What do you mean, "change it externally?" And I don't need variable sizes, just 600x600.

Comment: `setPreferredsize()` will just do nothin'.

Comment: no, it will set the panel's size to 600x600. I always have done it this way.

Comment: Well, not if you override `getPreferredSize()` :)

Comment: oh, that makes sense. but why do this and not just `setPreferredSize`?

Comment: could you please clarify why I can't just use `setPreferredSize`?