# JTextField suddenly too small

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Screenshot:

[image]

The `textfield` always worked fine, but suddenly was too small. You can still enter text, and when clicking the Print textJOptionPane.

I also tried both

```
JTextField tfld = new JTextField(10);
```

and

```
JTextField tfld = new JTextField("test adlfjsdlfjasdf");
```

but neither one helped.

Comment: This is probably due to your layout manager. Can you post a Short, [Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: A related example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try you use

```
         txtfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(int,int));
```

it will take parameters for Dimension you can read this for further assistance

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are using a GridBagLayout. This happens on components that don't have a reasonable minimum size.