# settings bounds to JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager, jtextarea

I have a JTextField that a User and an Admin update to try and solve a problem that a user may have. Although when I setText(conversation) to the JTextField the text starts in the middle and when it goes to the end of a line it does not go to a different line. Can I set the JTextField so that text begins at the top? and when the user/admin gets to the side of the text field it goes to another line? I have tried looking this up everywhere and can not find an answer

**here is a picture of the window with the conversation text field**

[image]

Comment: Try JTextArea instead and place it in a JScrollPane

Comment: Do use `JTextArea`; [do _not_ set bounds on a non-resizable container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just noticed that you are using a JTextField. JTextField is a single line and will hence print the text that appears to be center aligned. You should be using a JTextArea instead that that is multi-lineand it will solve your problem