# Why netbeans considering the object of swing component as package

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm trying to create a simple JFrame with some scomponents like JTextField and JButton
The below code is not showing any error,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Commform 
{
    static final JFrame common = new JFrame();
    JTextField Farmername = new JTextField();
    Commform()
    {
        common.getContentPane().setLayout(null);  
        Farmername.setBounds(100, 100, 285, 100);      
    }

}
```

But, after declaring the object for JFrame (common) and JTextField (Farmername), if I try to use setBounds method before the constructor like the bolded line,

```
public class Commform 
{
    static final JFrame common = new JFrame();
    JTextField Farmername = new JTextField();

    Farmername.setBounds(100, 100, 285, 100);

    Commform()
    {
        common.getContentPane().setLayout(null);    

    }
}
```

then netbeans underlines in red color and shows the tooltip as "**package Farmername does not exist,  illegal start or expression**"
When I am able to use object inside constructor, why can't I use just after creating the object ?

And even using the Farmername inside static, as shown below doesn't give any error.

```
static
    {        
        System.out.println("Called from main function");
        common.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        Farmername.setBounds(100, 100, 285, 100);
    }
```

I'm creating this form in the class without main function because I would like to call this frame and enter credentials to insert them to database, later to display particular person's credentials in their respective text field, I want to call this same frame. But at any level I don't want to use main function to this class.

Please help me.

Comment: Is this a typo `Formername`vs `**Farmername` ?

Comment: You're mixing a method invocation with field declarations. See [*Initializing Fields*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html),  learn [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and use conventional names.

Comment: Sorry @PeterMmm I was intended to bold that line. And its Farmername not Formername.

Comment: Thank you very much @trashgod [Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) is the perfect answer I was searching.

Comment: Off-topic: should avoid using `null` layout and use a suitable [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Also see [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529200/non-resizable-window-border-and-positioning/12532237#12532237)  about using `setBounds()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
Farmername.setBounds(100, 100, 285, 100);
```

needs to be inside of a block, whether it be a method or a constructor. Whenever you're trying to invoke a change to property via a method, it can't occur in the data field region of the code. It needs to be withing a block.