# JLabel text being cut off

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jframe, jlabel

[image]

As you can see from the image above some of the text is being cut off :(
 Code:

```
package malgm.school.clockui.ui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

import malgm.school.clockui.ClockUI;
import malgm.school.clockui.ResourceLoader;

public class ClockFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    public final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;

    public ClockFrame() {
        setTitle("Clock");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        relocalize();
    }

    public void relocalize() {
        //Wipe controls
        this.getContentPane().removeAll();
        this.setLayout(null);

        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setLayout(new BoxLayout(header, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        JPanel section = new JPanel();
        section.setLayout(new BoxLayout(section, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("The time is...");

        JButton speakButton = new JButton("Speak");
        speakButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

                try {
                    Process pr = rt.exec(ClockUI.dir + "/SpeakingClock.exe");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        JLabel time = new JLabel("test");
        ResourceLoader resLoader = new ResourceLoader();
        time.setFont(resLoader.getFont(ResourceLoader.FONT_DIGITAL, 72));

        section.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        section.add(time);
        section.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        header.add(label);
        header.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        header.add(speakButton);

        add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(section, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

FONT: http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Reimeus could you please find me a tutorial or example or such to help? I'm using a BorderLayout and a BoxLayout already

Comment: call `pack()` to sizes components

Comment: @nachokk where would I place this?

Comment: As an advice don't call your class Frame , you have imported ` java.awt.Frame`

Comment: OK, I didn't think about that, I'm teaching some mates how to make a clock :) And the one mate made a speaking clock in C# with me.

Comment: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) before you call `setVisible(true)` , setting null layout is a waste of time, don't know why you do that and remove all in constructor.. is not necessary

Comment: @nachokk I want my frame to be a specific size tho

Comment: override `getPreferredSize()` in a JPanel, add components to that, and add that panel to the frame..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
JLabel time = new JLabel("test");
ResourceLoader resLoader = new ResourceLoader();
time.setFont(resLoader.getFont(ResourceLoader.FONT_DIGITAL, 72));
```

Add `time.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 20, 20));`

After it will look like:

```
JLabel time = new JLabel("test");
ResourceLoader resLoader = new ResourceLoader();
time.setFont(resLoader.getFont(ResourceLoader.FONT_DIGITAL, 72));
time.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 20, 20));
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A key to success with Swing [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is to avoid `setLayout(null)` and to `pack()` the enclosing `Window`. This lets the contained components adopt their preferred sizes, as shown below. To avoid this [pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513), don't invoke `setResizable(false)`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551260/230513 */
public class ClockFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClockFrame cf = new ClockFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public ClockFrame() {
        setTitle("Clock");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void initComponents() {
        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setLayout(new BoxLayout(header, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JPanel section = new JPanel();
        section.setLayout(new BoxLayout(section, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("The time is...");
        JButton speakButton = new JButton("Speak");
        JLabel time = new JLabel("00:00");
        time.setFont(time.getFont().deriveFont(72f));
        section.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        section.add(time);
        section.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        header.add(label);
        header.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        header.add(speakButton);
        add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(section, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

change your constructor definition to (EDITED)

```
public Frame() {
    setTitle("Clock");
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    relocalize();
    setSize(850, 650);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, when you use pack() you size the frame around the components within the frame, making the frame a title bar and nothing else

Comment: try this public Frame() {
        setTitle("Clock");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        relocalize();
        setSize(850, 650);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: @rahulpasricha edit your original answer instead of posting new code as comment.