# Using JTextField makes everything else dissappear

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I tried to put a text field and a button and label using Swing in Java.I successfully added the label and the button but if I try to add the text field, the hole frame is blank, so nothing shows up, not even the button or the label.
What I am doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingPartOne extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SwingPartOne();
}

public SwingPartOne(){
    this.setSize(800,800);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();

    int xPos = (dim.height / 2) - (this.getHeight() / 2);
    int yPos = (dim.width / 2) - (this.getWidth() / 2);

    this.setResizable(false);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setTitle("First Jframe");


    JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Some random text .");

    label1.setText("New text.");

    label1.setToolTipText("Surprize!");

    JButton thebutton1 = new JButton("BOOM!");

    JTextField textField = new JTextField("Some text" , 15);
    textField.setColumns(5);
    textField.setSize(200,200);
    textField.setText("Some random text");

    thePanel.add(label1);
    thePanel.add(textField);
    thePanel.add(thebutton1);
    this.add(thePanel);






}
}
```

Comment: Call `this.setVisible(true)` at the end of the constructor so it can `validate`. Also, some other notes: 1) `textField.setSize(200,200);` won't do much, override it's `getPreferredSize` method instead (only if you really need to). 2) To center the frame, you can also simply call `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`. There's no need to calculate `xPos` and `yPos`

Comment: [Beware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513) `setResizable(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by putting `this.setVisible(true)` at the end by the LuxxMiner`s help .

>
Call this.setVisible(true) at the end of the constructor so it can validate. Also, some other notes: 1) textField.setSize(200,200); won't do much, override it's getPreferredSize method instead (only if you really need to). 2) To center the frame, you can also simply call setLocationRelativeTo(null). There's no need to calculate xPos and yPose