# Create GridBagLayout fixed size buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to create buttons for a GUI that have 3 different fixed sizes. I want the size of the buttons to be independent of the `String` inside them. Is that possible with `GridBagLayout`?

Comment: `GridLayout` yes, `GridBagLayout` not as far as I understand.. ***unless*** you use a hack to write the strings to same sized images & use the images as icons for the buttons.

Comment: After considering why you want to do this, please ensure that the resulting buttons are no smaller than their preferred size.

Comment: `3 different fixed sizes.` - define what that means to you. Do you just want to change the Font to make the displayed text easier to read? Do you just want to increase the Border around the button but keep the text the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, consider using an available [`sizeVariant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).

[image]

If you pursue a custom `ButtonUI` approach, shown in the last row, please ensure that the resulting buttons are no smaller than their preferred size. Doing so in your implementation of [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) will help avoid the pitfall seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801762/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the preferredSize on the button(s) to the size you want.  Like this:

```
myButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

If for some reason that doesn't keep the button's size fixed, try setting the button's maximumSize and minimumSize to the same dimension.

```
myButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
myButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

This would get your button fixed to *one* size.  I'm not sure how you could fix it to multiple sizes, like a small, medium, or large size (based on its text).