# Change the icon for the popup calendar in JDatePicker jar file

Tags: java, swing, date, jframe, jcalendar

I have searched in many sites to add the icon of calendar in JDatePicker jar file. It shows ... instead of icon of Calendar.  And also how to disable the before dates till today? Could anyone have idea to do this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post a [mcve] where we can copy-paste and see the issue, I think it's a layout issue

Comment: You shouldcheck the API. Usualy you will find a method named getComponent(int). One of the components should be the button you are looking for.  All components of the swing may be reacheable like this... unless they are not. :)

Comment: @Frakcool is correct: it's a [layout problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37800301/230513). Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on a single problem.