# Java Swings Auto-Resize Pictures

Tags: java, swing, autoresize

I'm doing this project using Swing.
To add a more welcoming feel to the UI, I'm also adding a few Photoshopped images as the background.Here's where the problem begins...
I want the images to automatically resize themselves once the size of the window is increased or decreased, how can I make this happen ?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876708/dynamically-resize-jframe-image-or-scroll/46879727#46879727) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798156/resizing-icon-to-fit-on-jbutton-in-java/25798462#25798462)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel to paint the image using the `drawImage(....)` method.

Another option is use a JLabel with an Icon as the background for the frame. Then you can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will automatically scale based on the space available to the label. This is the most flexible solution since the `StretchIcon` can be used on any component that supports icons.

You can also check out the [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which allows you to display an image. You can display the image at its actual size, scaled or tiled.